# Change all values generically in array of objects with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to change all values that may be turned into a number but come as a string

```
const array = [{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: '1',
  decimal: '0.1'
},{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: '2',
  decimal: '0.4'
}]
```

I would like to use this condition for all the values:

```
const returnValue = !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? parseFloat(val) : val
```

But not really sure how to iterate over the array of object without specifying each `key`.

I have done this, but not sure how efficient it is

```js
const res = json.map(obj => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    obj[key] = !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) ? parseFloat(value) : value
  }
  return obj
})

console.log(res)
```

Desired output

```
const array = [{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: 1, // <-- Number
  decimal: 0.1 // <-- Number
},{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: 2,  // <-- Number
  decimal: 0.4 // <-- Number
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy

```js
const array = [{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: '1',
  decimal: '0.1'
},{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: '2',
  decimal: '0.4'
}]

const returnValue = val => !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? parseFloat(val) : val

const a2 = array.map(
   obj => Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).map(
        ([key, value]) => [key, returnValue(value)]
      )
   )
)

console.log(a2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually this is 7% slower than my propoposition and 15% slower than @Nitheesh

Comment: I'm sure of it... but does not mutate the original array

Comment: Mine does not mutate the array either

Comment: hmm.. It mutate Objects inside array, or I missing something?

Comment: Yeah you are right, not really sure if it's a problem in my case thou, but yes you are correct. And actually your proposal for non mutation is faster than @Nitheesh

Answer (score 1):

To update the same Array, just use `Array.forEach`, if you want to create a new Array, use `Array.map` approach

**`Array.forEach` approach**

```js
const array = [
  { label: "foo", page: 1, rank: "1", decimal: "0.1" },
  { label: "foo", page: 1, rank: "1", decimal: "0.1" },
];
array.forEach((value) => {
  Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    value[key] = !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? parseFloat(val) : val;
  });
});
console.log(array);
```

**`Array.map` approach**

```js
const array = [
  { label: "foo", page: 1, rank: "1", decimal: "0.1" },
  { label: "foo", page: 1, rank: "1", decimal: "0.1" },
];
const response = array.map((value) => {
  return Object.entries(value).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    acc[key] = !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? parseFloat(val) : val;
    return acc;
  }, {});
});
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: '1',
  decimal: '0.1'
},{
  label: 'foo',
  page: 1,
  rank: '1',
  decimal: '0.1'
}]

const parsedArray = array.map(element => 
  Object.entries(element).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => {
    return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: isFinite(+value) ? +value : value,
    }
},{}));

console.log(parsedArray);
```

Comment: Instead of the reduce method, you can use `Object.fromEntries()` as other answers suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using **lodash** library ([mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues)), you can reduce the amount of code.

```js
const array = [{label: 'foo',page: 1,rank: '1',decimal: '0.1'},{label: 'foo',page: 1,rank: '2',decimal: '0.4'}];

const result = array.map(obj => _.mapValues(obj, value => Number(value) || value));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```